# how to sent byte[ ] array in socket

Tags: java, arrays, string, sockets

I'm a newbie in Java, I'm trying to sent a byte [] array via socket, but it itself convert my array to string and then sends it. so far it's ok, but the problem is that I need to either receive the message in array type, OR I have to convert the string to array, in order to make the decrypt method be able to decrypt the array (the input of decrypt method must be byte array). how can I do that?

my serverside related code is:

```
private void IssuingTickets() throws Exception{

        String socketUsername = reader.readLine();//rcv username
        String socketPassword = reader.readLine();//rcv password
        writer.println("Lemme Check!");  


        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("input"));
        String fileUsername = prop.getProperty("username");
        String filePassword = null;
        if (prop.getProperty("password") != null) {
            filePassword = prop.getProperty("password");}
        if (socketPassword.equals(filePassword)){ 
            String sessionKeyBobKdc = new Scanner(new File("sBOBandKDC")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            byte[] ClientTicket = encrypt(sessionKeyBobKdc, filePassword);
            System.out.println("clietn ticket =   " + ClientTicket+"   ArraytoString   " + Arrays.toString(ClientTicket));
            writer.println(ClientTicket);
            String KDCkey = new Scanner(new File("KDCkey")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            String UnEncTGT= sessionKeyBobKdc.concat(socketUsername);
            byte[] TGT = encrypt(UnEncTGT, KDCkey);
            writer.println(TGT);

            }else
                {writer.println("Please try again later!");}

            }    


    public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText1, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }



    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),"UTF-8");
            }
}
```

the Clientside related code is:

```
        private void recieveTickts() throws IOException, InterruptedException, Exception{
                String msg = reader.readLine(); //Lemme  check
                System.out.println("Server :" + msg); 
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                String  Sth = reader.readLine(); //please try again
                if(Sth.equals("Please try again later!")){
                    System.out.println(Sth);
                    System.exit(1);
                }else{
                ClientTicket = Sth;
                String TGT = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Encrypted key between Client and KDC is  " + ClientTicket + "  and the TGT is " + TGT);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                System.out.println("SUCCESSFUL"); }          
                byte[] b = ClientTicket.getBytes();
                System.out.println("b= " + b);
                String sessionKeyBobKdc = decrypt(b, Password);
                System.out.println(Password + "session key is "+ sessionKeyBobKdc);
        }
```

thanx in advanced guys..

Comment: Why don't you just change your `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods to work in terms of byte arrays rather than strings? That would be a much better idea, IMO. Let the caller do any text-to-binary conversion they need.

Comment: Hint: never ever go with empty catch blocks. Hiding error messages is the **last** thing you want to do.

Comment: thanks Jon for fast response, actually encrypt and decrypt methods Are working with byte array now

Comment: thanks GhostCat, I'll fix it asap

Answer (score -1):

I documented the code to help you out but that is basically a quick and dirty way to never stop listening for data and then also return the received as `byte[]`. *If you don't need to listen at all times just modify this code to stop listening once you received your message*

You can make this more dynamic with using parameters for defining the sign that a message is finished etc.

I used a StringBuilder to act as a little buffer. And defined that a message is finished once I receive a LF. Everything else get's put into the "buffer". Additionally I filter out CR since I don't want them in my message.

```
Socket client;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result = "";
int c;
try
{
  InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
  while ( ( c = inputStream.read() ) >= 0 ) // Loop to listen for data until the connection is dead
  {
    if ( c == 0x0a ) // 0x0a is the hex for a LineFeed ( LF )
    {
      result = sb.toString(); // put everything you received so far as a final message
      sb.delete( 0, sb.length() ); // clear your message "buffer"
    }
    else if ( c != 0x0d /* <CR> */ ) // Not necessary but it helps keeping the message clear
    {
      sb.append( (char) c ); // add the received integer as char to the message "buffer"
    }
    if ( !result.isEmpty() ) // Catch that a message is received
    {
      log.fine( "received message: " + result ); // just log for tracing
      return result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // return the byte[] of the message with the needed Charset.         
    }
  }
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
  log.warning( e.getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: No Problem. As a note. I forgot to mention that `client.getInputStream()` is from a `Socket` I declared as client. I hope that the comments help you in understanding a little bit.

Comment: This is no improvement whatsoever over `BufferedReader.readLine()`, and as the ciphertext can contain both LF and CR any time it likes, and as neither `String` nor `StringBuffer` is a container for binary data, the entire scheme of trying to use line I/O is doomed.

Comment: @EJP True but I understood he wants to implement Socket functionality now and this is how I did it in a custom requirement that works perfectly for me. 

I stated he should modify it to his needs. If he does not plan to use Socket and tcp my whole answer is deprecated.